# Creating XML file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, parsing

I'd like to be able to create a simple XML only using Javascript:

```
var xml_str = "";

var parser = new DOMParser();
var docu = parser.parseFromString(xml_str, "text/xml");
```

Expected output :

```
<root>
<subroot>
   <name></name>
   <surname></surname>
   <age></age>
   <color></color>


</subroot>
</root>
```

And adding textNodes to name,surname,age,color...

Comment: What is `estructura`?  And the question seems to be asking how to make xml, but your logic seems to be attempting to *parse* xml.  Those are not the same thing.

Comment: Creating a string representation of xml seems like it would involve https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer

Comment: @Taplar estructura was misspelled.